# Salvar um PDF no SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Sou iniciante e estou com dificuldade de salvar o pdf no banco, nem sei como posso fazer isso.

```
botaoBusca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("application/pdf");
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);    
            }    
        });

        salvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {    

                    //PDFViewToByte(imageView);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Salvo com Sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }catch (Exception e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Erro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }    
            }
        });          
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode==1)
        {
            Uri PDFSelecionada = data.getData();
            String [] colunas = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(PDFSelecionada,colunas, null,null,null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int indexColuna = cursor.getColumnIndex(colunas[0]);
            String pathPDF = cursor.getString(indexColuna);

            cursor.close();    
            textView.setText("PDF Carregado");        
        }    
    }

    private byte[] PDFViewToByte(File pdf) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream( pdf );
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)pdf.length() ];
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0)
        {
            offset += numRead;
        }          

        return bytes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salvar um arquivo pdf no sqlite do Android não é uma pratica muito recomendada.

A melhor solução e mais recomendada seria você salvar no armazenamento interno do app e salvar na sua tabela do SQLite apenas a referência para esse arquivo. Salvar aquivos em um banco de dados não é uma boa prática.

Aqui https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific você vai encontrar a documentação para entender um pouco mais sobre como utilizar esse recurso de armazenamento interno do app no Android.